# Access KeyCloak's Identity Token from Java Application

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using KeyCloak for user authentication and authorization. Now I want to get/access identity token generated by KeyCloak after user login through my java application.

Comment: U just need token or an access to keycloak via ur main account? can you clarify what you are trying to do? mb getting users info? roles?

Comment: I need authentication code..